# iOS - In app purchase - Get product list from web app

Tags: ios, rest, in-app-purchase

I have a real problem here:

Is there a way to retrieve the in-app-purchase product list from a web app using web services?

I need to get the list of products ids I added on itunes from my web app, but can't find any documentation on how to integrate with this.

Is this possible? Have any of you done this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use Parse and keep a list of product identifiers in my database. As I add or remove products, I update Parse.
As far as I'm aware StoreKit does not return a list of product identifiers.

Comment: Hi @stevekohls could you please tell me more about how you managed to keep Parse and the app store in sync?

Comment: Hi @danielrvt, I do this manually. When I use iTunes Connect to add or remove an IAP product, I manually edit the Parse database as well.

Comment: @stevekohls do you have sample code on how you pull the products from the web service!?

Comment: @Learn2Code I no longer use Parse. I use CloudKit and I manually add the IAP product info to my CloudKit database and to iTunes Connect. When my app runs, I get the list of available products using StoreKit, and then I use the product identifiers to get my product info from CloudKit.

Comment: @stevekohls, i figured as much with Parse no longer in service, but can you show code on how you retrieve the product info from cloudkit , i myself am trying to get it from firebase, but I am not be able to do so thus far!?